# How do I select a sprite on a first mouse click then create a new one in the position of a second mouse click

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a simple game that requires you to be able to select a sprite by clicking on it and then place a new instance of the sprite you selected onto the location of a second mouse click.

```
#Creating the sprite
addBarrierButton = Barrier()

addBarrierButton.rect.x=800
addBarrierButton.rect.y=400
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.group()
all_sprites_list.add(addBarrierButton)
all_sprites_list.draw(gameDisplay)

#Main loop

while True:
    ev = pygame.event.get()
    for event in ev: 
        if event.type = pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if addBarrierButton.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            #Here is where I am stuck... I need it to wait for a second 
            #click 
            #and then create a new barrier at the position of that click
```

The major problem is that I couldn't find a way to wait for a second click after the first click.

Comment: use variable `selected = False` to control if you already clicked on object. When you click then you check `selected` and you know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to *wait* for a second click. You need to be able to understand if, when clicking, the program should select the sprite or create a new one.

A way to do this is to create a variable `selected_sprite`. If this variable is equal to `None`, that means that the click must select a sprite. It this variable holds a sprite, you can create a copy of it (or just a new sprite) at the new position.

I reworked your code to show how to do:

```
addBarrierButton = Barrier()

addBarrierButton.rect.x=800
addBarrierButton.rect.y=400

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.group()
all_sprites_list.add(addBarrierButton)
all_sprites_list.draw(gameDisplay)

selected_sprite = None

#Main loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type = pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if selected_sprite is None:
                for spr in all_sprites_list:
                    if spr.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        selected_sprite = spr
                        break
            else:
                new_sprite = Barrier()
                new_sprite.image = selected_sprite.image
                new_sprite.rect.x = event.pos[0]
                new_sprite.rect.y = event.pos[1]
                all_sprites_list.add(new_sprite)
                selected_sprite = None
```